# Error with MySQL Subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a MySQL query to produce a view which displays two columns, the two columns are sub query's but for some reason I am getting error.

```
SELECT 
(SUM(cards_required) FROM `orders` WHERE statuses = 1) As Count,
(SUM(cards_required) FROM `orders` WHERE statuses = 2) As Count
FROM `orders` WHERE user_id = 1
```

**error message**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM orders WHERE statuses = 1) As Count, (SUM(cards_required)
>   FROM orders ' at line 3

Comment: dont see any error message

Comment: That's what I thought @amdixon

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `orders` WHERE statuses = 1) As Count,
(SUM(cards_required) FROM `orders` ' at line 3

Comment: ok youve got multiple where clauses and from clauses - why ?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're using isn't quite right. You can use `IF` to conditionally sum:

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(statuses = 1,cards_required,0)) As status_1,
SUM(IF(statuses = 2,cards_required,0)) As status_2
FROM `orders` WHERE user_id = 1
```

Comment: Wow that worked! I usually work in SQL seems there are more differences than I thought!